# HTML5 input type file's multiple attribute not working in IE?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I want to create a multi file uploder using HTML5 and PHP5. I don't want to use any flash player for support. Flash uploader will not support in iphone. I created the form like this

```
<form name="uploader" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple="multiple" />

    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" /> 

</form>
```

It is working with chrome, mozilla, opera, safari... but IE not supporting this.

I tried with IE8 and IE9 both are not supporting. How can I fix this? Anybody who knows the solution please kindly help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE8 does not support HTML5. Perhaps IE9 is running in compatibility mode? Press F12 to bring up the developer tools and in the top menu you can change the settings in what mode it is in.

Maybe it is a solution to use a Java or Flash based system for multiple uploads. Also, these will also usually support drag and drop of files.

Comment: Hi Craig White I cant use java my site is already started to develop using PHP5. Also I cant use flash its not supporting in Ipads. I changed IE9 browser mode still its not working?

Comment: I am not referring to java on a server side. You can running Java applets on the users side without having compatibility on your site. It simply communicates with your PHP. But flash is a much better solution as it is more common and doesn't require special permissions to run.

Answer (score 19):

A few things:

1. IE doesn't support multiple file upload
2. Flash is currently the way to get round that, or just to drop to single uploads in IE
3. The iPad doesn't support Flash, but also doesn't support file uploads
4. The usage of IE is much higher than iOS

So, the logical conclusion is either:

- Use multiple uploads in new browsers, and single in older ones – IE users won't notice, as they have never been able to upload multiple files anyway!
- Use Flash as a fallback in older browsers

(Update: iOS6 now does allow file upload, including multiple uploads)

Comment: iOS does support uploading images to a file input field.

Comment: Note the update – it didn't back in 2011 when iOS5 was the newest.

Answer (score 4):

IE9 does not support multiple file uploads or the File API, according to [this source](http://caniuse.com/#search=HTML5%20form%20features). Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963903/why-did-ie9-leave-out-support-for-the-file-api-and-the-multiple-attribute-on-file) on SO asking the same question with the same answer. Like Craig says, your best bet for now is to use Flash as a replacement in IE and older browsers; such a solution is employed by [Dojo 1.6](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/uploader/).

Comment: flash player is not working with Ipads so I am trying with jquery and HTML5

Comment: But iPads don't support file upload from the browser anyway, correct?

Comment: If you are not tied down to jQuery, the Dojo site I linked to does have a solution to this without Flash (using an IFrame). I don't know how it looks, but you may want to look at it. But if not, I love jQuery, so by all means, proceed.

Comment: Excellent point, Stoive. Learned something new today, it seems. Relevant source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081997/upload-files-via-ipad

Answer (score 0):

Two potential fallback options:

- http://www.plupload.com/
- http://clubajax.org/the-new-dojo-html5-multi-file-uploader/