# IE8 - input (type="file") get files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a problem with input (type="file") in Internet Explorer (I have tested only in 8).

HTML

```
<input id="drop-file-files" class="drop-file-waiting" type="file">
```

JS (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js)

```
$('#drop-file-files').change(function(e){
    $.each(e.target.files, function(index, file){
        alert(file);
    });
});
```

It work perfect in Firefox, Chrome and Safari return Object File, but IE return a error because "files" in e.target is undefined. Someone know how can I get this "files" using JavaScript?

EDITED: Documentation [MSDN input type=file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Only in IE10 [files property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 does not support multiple files. This has been [already discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207388/is-it-possible-to-select-and-upload-multiple-files-at-one-time-in-internet-explo). You can at least get the filename via `e.target.value`.

Comment: Ok I know that does not support multiples files, but how can I get information for the file?

Comment: @ThyagoQuintas Does `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]` work for you?

Comment: No, dataTransfer is empty after I selected a file.

Comment: @ThyagoQuintas Sorry, mixed something up. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Matthias then how to get single file?