# How to get files from <input type='file' .../> (indirect) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the "input tag" in non-IE browsers:

```
<input type="file" ...
```

I'm trying to write my uploader, just using JavaScript and ASP.NET.

I have no problem uploading files.

My problem occurred when I wanted to get my files in non-IE browsers with

```
<input type="file" ...
```

I do not want to use directly from `input` because its appearance does not change correctly.

I wrote this code to get files from the hard disk:

```
function $tag(_str_tag) {
    return document.getElementsByTagName(_str_tag);
}

function $create(_str_tag) {
    return document.createElement(_str_tag);
}


function $open_file() {
    _el_upload = $create("input");
    _el_body = $tag("body")[0];
    _el_upload.setAttribute("type", "file");
    _el_upload.style.visibility = "hidden";
    _el_upload.setAttribute("multiple", "multiple");
    _el_upload.setAttribute("position", "absolute");
    _el_body.appendChild(_el_upload);
    _el_upload.click();
    _el_body.removeChild(_el_upload);
    return _el_upload.files;
}
```

In IE it works pretty well and returns my files currently.. In Chrome And Firefox, after loading "file input dialog", it can't return any file.

And Opera and Safari are completely out.

I can fix it with this trick, but it's not good basically.

```
_el_upload.click();
alert();
```

I think a "callback" or "wait function" may fix this, but I can't handle it.

Comment: What do you mean by `its appearance does not change correctly`  What are you trying to do?

Comment: You need to use the `onchange` event of the `<input>` element.  `return _el_upload.files` happens *before* you select a file.

Comment: hi @RocketHazmat thx for reply : i am tring to make my own UI in my CMS and i have problem with <input type="file"/> design ; i dont want to see a textbox nearby a button named "file upload"

Comment: I'm testing "onchange"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048026/open-file-dialog-box-in-javascript.

Comment: @RayNicholus : Consider the Alert : When Alert is called, the code will be stopped, to Alert end ; i want this for "INPUT FILE DIALOG".

Comment: **onchange** not working or I do not know how to do it?
I use it as a callback function.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I dont want to use jQuery

Comment: Maybe its because i'm not english and I cant explain what I mean :D

Comment: its Invert [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830058/ie8-input-type-file-get-files?rq=1]

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you are looking to style a file input element, look at [open file dialog box in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048026/open-file-dialog-box-in-javascript).  If you are looking to grab the files associated with a file input element, you must do something like this:

```
inputElement.onchange = function(event) {
   var fileList = inputElement.files;
   //TODO do something with fileList.  
}
```

See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileList) for more info on the `FileList` type.

Note that the code above will only work in browsers that support the File API.  For IE9 and earlier, for example, you only have access to the file name.  The input element has no `files` property in non-File API browsers.

Answer (score 25):

Based on Ray Nicholus's answer :

```
inputElement.onchange = function(event) {
   var fileList = inputElement.files;
   //TODO do something with fileList.  
}
```

using this will also work :

```
inputElement.onchange = function(event) {
   var fileList = event.target.files;
   //TODO do something with fileList.  
}
```

Comment: It could also "event.currentTarget.files".

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are pretty sufficient. Additional to the `onChange`, if you upload a file using drag and drop events, you can get the file in `drop` event by accessing `eventArgs.dataTransfer.files`.