# How to trigger INPUT FILE event REACTJS by another DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **INPUT BUTTON** and **INPUT FILE**, I want to click the **BUTTON** and it will trigger the **INPUT FILE** event in **REACT JS.**

```
React.createElement('input',{type:'file', name:'myfile'})
```

then the button

```
React.createElement('a',{onClick: this.doClick},'Select File')
```

So how to define and trigger the INPUT FILE click event when we click the A HREF?

Your help is appreciate.
:-)

Answer (score -24, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is a question I answered a long time ago not knowing very much react at this time. The fun thing is that it has been considered valid ^^.

So for anyone reading this answer; **this answer is wrong and is a very good example of something you shouldn't do in react.**

Please find below **a nice anti-pattern**, again, **don't do it.**

=================================================

You can achieve this using jQuery:

```
this.doClick: function() {
    $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
}
```

React does not provide specific functions to trigger events, you can use jQuery or simply native Javascript: see [Creating and triggering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) events on MDN

Comment: React.createElement('input',{type:'file', name:'myfile'})

then the button

React.creatElement('a',{onClick: this.doClick},'Select File')

So how to define and trigger the INPUT FILE click event when we click the A HREF?

Comment: Yes, currently I always do like that, but what I need is to find is there any way to trigger by REACT, not by JQUERY

Comment: The reason one would use React is to get away from jQuery. This answer is poor.

Comment: jQuery completely gives control of the DOM and react does the opposite. It's highly recommended that they should never be used together.

Answer (score 62):

**Update: Sep 18, 2021**

Note: On NextJS, I was facing `onChange` event is not trigged from input file element. For that, we can use `onInputCapture` or `onChangeCapture`. For more detailed information, [Stackoverflow - onChange event is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69231011/4067157)

Basic example on `onChangeCapture` as per our requirement. Requires React ^16.8,

```
const Dummy = () => {
  const inputFileRef = React.useRef();
  const onFileChangeCapture = ( e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> ) {
    /*Selected files data can be collected here.*/
    console.log(e.target.files);
  };
  const onBtnClick = () => {
    /*Collecting node-element and performing click*/
    inputFileRef.current.click();
  };
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type="file"
        ref={inputFileRef}
        onChangeCapture={onFileChangeCapture}
      />
      <button onClick={onBtnClick}>Select file</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Using **useRef** Hook in functional components. Requires React ^16.8,

```
const Dummy = () => {
  const inputFileRef = useRef( null );

  const onFilechange = ( e ) => {
    /*Selected files data can be collected here.*/
    console.log( e.target.files );
  }
  const onBtnClick = () => {
    /*Collecting node-element and performing click*/
    inputFileRef.current.click();
  }

  return (
    <form className="some-container">
      <input
        type="file"
        ref={inputFileRef}
        onChange={onFileChange}
      />
      <button onClick={onBtnClick}>Select file</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Class Implementation with **React.createRef()** and handling click with **node element**.

```
class Dummy extends React.Component {
    
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );

    this.inputFileRef = React.createRef();
    this.onFileChange = this.handleFileChange.bind( this );
    this.onBtnClick = this.handleBtnClick.bind( this );
  }

  handleFileChange( e ) {
    /*Selected files data can be collected here.*/
    console.log( e.target.files );
  }

  handleBtnClick() {
    /*Collecting node-element and performing click*/
    this.inputFileRef.current.click();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="some-container">
        <input
          type="file"
          ref={this.inputFileRef}
          onChange={this.onFileChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onBtnClick}>Select file</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the right approach and rightfully should have been an accepted answer.

Comment: so how to save the uploaded file in state variable? I added a onChange in input but it is not working ??

Comment: handle it using onChange property in input tag.

```<input type="file" onChange={( e ) => e.target.files[0]} />```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15792918/4067157)

Comment: How do you ensure that the ref has been populated though? It doesn't trigger a render, so the first render the ref is always null in a funcctional component. Is it considered a best practice to just re-render every first time just to grab ref instances?

Comment: this.onBtnClick = this.handleBtnClick.bind( this ); ====> should be ====> this.onBtnClick = this.onBtnClick.bind( this );

Comment: Hi @JoelHager, Event will be triggered after the component mount and user clicks on the html tag. So basically after the mount, the ref will get initialised. If there is any possibilities that we're missing out, then give a torch to my darkened mind.

Answer (score 39):

You don't need jQuery for this. You don't even need an event handler. HTML has a specific element for this, called [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

First, make sure your `input` element has an `id` attribute:

```
React.createElement('input',{type:'file', name:'myfile', id:'myfile'})
```

Then, instead of:

```
React.createElement('a',{onClick: this.doClick},'Select File')
```

Try:

```
React.createElement('label',{htmlFor: 'myfile'},'Select File')
```

(Instead of adding `htmlFor` and `id` attributes, another solution is to make the `input` element a child of the `label`.)

Now clicking the `label` should trigger the same behaviour as clicking the `input` itself.

Comment: Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 35):

You could trigger the input type file with ref, f.e:

on your class component:

```
<input 
    ref={fileInput => this.fileInput = fileInput} 
    type="file"
 />
<button onClick={this.triggerInputFile}> Select File </button>
```

and make a function on that class component too:

```
triggerInputFile = () => this.fileInput.click()
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Hooks [with useref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
const FancyInput = () => {
    const fileInput = useRef(null)

    const handleClick = () => {
        fileInput.current.click()
    }

    const handleFileChange = event => {
        console.log("Make something")
    }

    return(
        <div className="patientactions-container">
            <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e)}
                ref={fileInput} 
            />
            <div onClick={() => handleClick()}></div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default FancyInput;
```

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting the error `Object is possibly 'null'.` when attempting to run `fileInput.current.click()`. I tried using an if statement to only run it if `fileInput.current !== null` but I am still getting the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Building on the answer from @YÒGÎ , here is an implementation using TypeScript:

```
class Dummy extends React.Component {
    fileInputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement> = React.createRef();

    forwardClickToInputElement = () => {
        this.fileInputRef.current!.click();
    };

    handleUploadDemand = (ie: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const fileList: FileList = ie.target.files;

        // do something with the FileList, for example:
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = () => {
            const str = String(fileReader.result);
            try {
                const parsedContent = YOUR_OWN_PARSING(str);
            } catch (error) {
                // YOUR OWN ERROR HANDLING
            }
        };
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileList[0])
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="some-container">
                <button onClick={this.forwardClickToInputElement}>Select File</button>
                <input ref={this.fileInputRef} type="file" onChange={this.handleSelectFile} hidden={true}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

References:

1. Solution for how to use refs in React with Typescript https://stackoverflow.com/a/50505931/2848676
2. Use ! operator for ref type narrowing https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-refs-with-typescript-a32d56c4d315

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to implement [Farid's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9773593/farid-murzone) answer in Typescript, can do the following:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
const FancyInput = () => {
  const fileInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

  const handleClick = () => {
    if(fileInput.current) {
      fileInput.current.click()
    }
  }

  const handleFileChange = event => {
      console.log("Make something")
  }

  return(
      <div className="patientactions-container">
          <input
              type="file"
              onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e)}
              ref={fileInput} 
          />
          <div onClick={() => handleClick()}></div>
      </div>
  )
}
export default FancyInput;
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone Looking for a Simple approach try this.

```
<div>
  <input type="file" name="library-images" id="library-images" hidden />
     <Button type='button' onClick={()=>{
                document.getElementById("library-images")?.click()
     }}>Upload</Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const CustomInput = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    document.getElementById("file_upload").click();
  };

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Make something");
  };

  return (
    <div className="patientactions-container">
      <input type="file" id="file_upload" onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(e)} />
      <div onClick={() => handleClick()}></div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CustomInput;
```