# How to use refs in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript with React. I'm having trouble understanding how to use refs so as to get static typing and intellisense with respect to the react nodes referenced by the refs. My code is as follows.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface AppState {
    count: number;
}

interface AppProps {
    steps: number;
}

interface AppRefs {
    stepInput: HTMLInputElement;
}

export default class TestApp extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState> {

constructor(props: AppProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        count: 0
    };
}

incrementCounter() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <input type="text" ref="stepInput" />
            <button onClick={() => this.incrementCounter()}>Increment</button>
            Count : {this.state.count}
        </div>
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 316, accepted):

If you’re using React 16.3+, the [suggested way](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to create refs is using `React.createRef()`.

```
class TestApp extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState> {
    private stepInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.stepInput = React.createRef();
    }
    render() {
        return <input type="text" ref={this.stepInput} />;
    }
}
```

When the component mounts, the `ref` attribute’s `current` property will be assigned to the referenced component/DOM element and assigned back to `null` when it unmounts. So, for example, you can access it using `this.stepInput.current`.

For more on `RefObject`, see [@apieceofbart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50505931/426839) or [the PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/12162) `createRef()` was added in.

---

If you’re using an earlier version of React (<16.3) or need more fine-grained control over when refs are set and unset, you can use [“callback refs”](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

```
class TestApp extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState> {
    private stepInput: HTMLInputElement;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.stepInput = null;
        this.setStepInputRef = element => {
            this.stepInput = element;
        };
    }
    render() {
        return <input type="text" ref={this.setStepInputRef} />
    }
}
```

When the component mounts, React will call the `ref` callback with the DOM element, and will call it with `null` when it unmounts. So, for example, you can access it simply using `this.stepInput`.

By defining the `ref` callback as a bound method on the class as opposed to an inline function (as in a [previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43726702/2) of this answer), you can avoid the callback [getting called twice during](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs) updates.

---

There [used to be](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) an API where the `ref` attribute was a string (see [Akshar Patel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33826399/426839)), but due to [some](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/8333#issuecomment-271648615) [issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1373), string refs are strongly discouraged and will eventually be removed.

---

*Edited May 22, 2018 to add the new way of doing refs in React 16.3. Thanks @apieceofbart for pointing out that there was a new way.*

Comment: Notice this is preferred way. Examples below with `refs` class attribute will be deprecated in upcoming React versions.

Comment: Please note that this is already an old way :) current is to use React.createRef()

Comment: @apieceofbart Thanks for the heads up. Updated the answer to include the new way.

Comment: I just don't see anything about typescript in your answer, I will add another answer

Comment: Whoops. Had Typescript in my original answer but forgot to include it in the new one. Added it back and linked to your answer as well. Thanks.

Comment: wow. i fell in love with tihs line: "private stepInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;"

Comment: You can also use `React.RefObject<HTMLElement>`

Comment: When I do that I get the following flow error `Cannot get 'React.RefObject' because property 'RefObject' is missing in  object type [1].Flow(prop-missing)`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 128):

#### `React.createRef` (class comp.)

```
class ClassApp extends React.Component {
  inputRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  
  render() {
    return <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef} />
  }
}
```

#### `React.useRef` (Hooks / function comp.)

a) Use readonly refs for React-managed DOM nodes:

```
const FunctionApp = () => {
  // note the passed-in `null` arg ----------------v
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
  return <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
}
```

`inputRef.current` becomes a [`readonly`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/82f5b794c1086b1b75a394c32d8d0ca3d1565ac3/types/react/index.d.ts#L87-L89) property by initializing its value with `null`.

b) Use [mutable refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) for arbitrary stored values akin to instance variables:

```
const FunctionApp = () => {
  const renderCountRef = useRef(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    renderCountRef.current += 1
  })
  // ... other render code
}
```

Note: Don't initialize `useRef` with [`null`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/82f5b794c1086b1b75a394c32d8d0ca3d1565ac3/types/react/index.d.ts#L1044) in this case - it would make the `renderCountRef` type `readonly` (see [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGbZFICippSGcAvnKVBCHAERSoacBQ-NBAB2heADF8IjMFEBBMGDgBeOAAoAlKoB8ufnENxhY+DxEATJFADCEaTDKqCxMgB4R+EACNrO9Z4ANoHaAPShxjwoMEiEcChwURaigQCeiEikAPLeAFb0MAZG4cai4olIltZ2Dk5qlO6ePtZwAD5wQYH+nWERaFExcQkAsvgwKN6BJJk5+RjYAO4AFsBoS3CEEIEAbrFw1mxQgkYu1LQF6lq6+icnJTBQwADmT9ZxB9BwC8Aw66TAUHK2xQjxQIiw8TiAAMyLMCgA6ND4KDmGBQuDAOJJFKpIq3CpVWz2cFkRHI1HOdTmKxE2qZMkoyrwAD8zLgAAZtABqOAARjxTE0ApK8NFcAgvxa1Jawis-EYQA)). If you *need to* provide `null` as initial value, do this:

```
const renderCountRef = useRef<number | null>(null)
```

#### Callback refs (both)

```
// Function component example, class analogue 
const FunctionApp = () => {
  const handleDomNodeChange = (domNode: HTMLInputElement | null) => {
    // ... do something with changed dom node.
  }
  return <input type="text" ref={handleDomNodeChange} />
}
```

Note: [String Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) are considered legacy and omitted for the scope of this answer.

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSGcAvnGVBCHAERSoYsCwAULwPT84AQQA2MJFAB2KGMABuSAFwChoSLEQcsuOGnaykyMtiKkKVHWeO16jZm23ceguADoPcFFIAmcdmCi6Eha6DBu1khkcAC0AHwExMbYyGFu+qgSNvF6BllRvKqqoRjpeUZRcAAUaEGEhHpMYG4AlEU8tSj1cADCdYTCYGBwSAAeEr4NqaU9TRBSSFLwOLxwa3DAUmD4MDYAvCXhGYbGADwAEgAqALIAMgCSWzskokggizBxVW18POtwAAtvD5XgARJgAOQgPiQPSBUgA5iEDlUfJDoco4Fc7o9tjAXm8PnAAD5wKT4USiFpwPYJFZ-f7rVxouCEJhIGAAzYIuAAd2AnL08KRfjRzCkGLcq3WNEKDLW7F8km+uGljP8HPw0jgpziavV61OmzxcBgAE8wEg9iwJOMWBqyHscJzgIQ3MadsY6Pw9fKDWsjU94ObLdbbTB7exHc6uW74SCkOCQFCYXDvEjvb7-acffrZTx8+1XNNwpFolVzhAIABrBpCMj4KQYYDzRrgVrtNDzQjwABijeb80GwxR1Npqr9rhQ1IMaKkojNDoaZGgcFBAHlrmSMYR9V2pD2NkH9ocIkkohcbg8gwT3ksvuTKT99a4AEbUkA7FCv15L+irlAoFfAUoEAxce2gJA-HkFBRHwJBCCUOA927eA2XeAA1WD4JPEszwqMgqgABh+f4zHISgMCqFVx3pf10KQLC4II9ItUVeAAGoDgARjzbAAG0AF1nz9dgYC1KQdR8BQswNQMTRDK0bTGCMHSdD1diiTN9X+U5pPkOJkCVKBGkbGAkJwBimJwrSc302SA34ezeELFx+GKHpYNEV90GrP8qlfCBOWpGJAUkEJ+UFBsmzkVsu3AeYiU7VDei8ny0GrYcaWqMc6RQg94HjMF0VTYVkWqMUU0xbFrzxW8iVJR8qRpPK-X+VwPDcOAWQYl1ET5AUASFdMoO6phtxhKU-Xzf4xIknUNNNC0lPDSMoidIrExK2Eyu0gs5SAA)

Comment: What's the difference between `useRef() as MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>` and `useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)` ?

Comment: Good question - the `current` property of `MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>` can be modified, whereas `useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)` creates a `RefObject` type with `current` marked as `readonly`. The former can be used, if you need to change current DOM nodes in refs yourself, e.g. in combination with an external library. It can also be written without `as`: `useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)`. The latter is a better choice for React managed DOM nodes, as used in most cases. React stores the nodes in the refs itself and you don't want to fumble around changing these values.

Comment: This should be the top answer since the use of hooks was added

Comment: It was passing the initial value of `null` that I was missing, thanks!

Comment: One may also do it this way:
Declare an interface `interface RefTypes {
  show: Function;
  hide: Function;
}` and then wherever the ref is used ==>
`const customRef = useRef<RefTypes >();`

Answer (score 40):

If you're using `React.FC`, add the `HTMLDivElement` interface:

```
const myRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

And use it like the following:

```
return <div ref={myRef} />;
```

Comment: Thanks. Another tip for anyone who comes across this is to check the Element. This example refers to the usage of a DIV element. A form for example would use - const formRef = React.useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you. Thank you.

Answer (score 35):

Since React 16.3 the way to add refs is to use [React.createRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) as Jeff Bowen pointed in his answer. However you can take advantage of Typescript to better type your ref.

In your example you're using ref on input element. So they way I would do it is:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    private inputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
    constructor() {
        ...
        this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    }

    ...

    render() {
        <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef} />;
    }
}
```

By doing this when you want to make use of that ref you have access to all input methods:

```
someMethod() {
    this.inputRef.current.focus(); // 'current' is input node, autocompletion, yay!
}
```

You can use it on custom components as well:

```
private componentRef: React.RefObject<React.Component<IProps>>;
```

and then have, for example, access to props :

```
this.componentRef.current.props; // 'props' satisfy IProps interface
```

Answer (score 33):

One way (which [I've been doing](https://github.com/TypeScriptBuilder/tsb/blob/824c89ae5dee588a45902e5089a273749396b174/src/app/renameVariable.tsx#L96-L97)) is to setup manually :

```
refs: {
    [string: string]: any;
    stepInput:any;
}
```

then you can even wrap this up in a nicer getter function (e.g. [here](https://github.com/TypeScriptBuilder/tsb/blob/824c89ae5dee588a45902e5089a273749396b174/src/app/findAndReplace.tsx#L93-L97)):

```
stepInput = (): HTMLInputElement => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.stepInput);
```

Comment: Thanks @basarat. I tried your solution but I'm getting this error 'Type Element is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement. Property accept is missing in type Element''

Comment: Might be an issue with the newer version of the react-dom definitions. Use as assertion in the meantime

Comment: Obviously `any` isn't mandatory here. Most examples I see use `HTMLInputElement`. Just stating the obvious, but if your ref is on a React component (i.e. `PeoplePicker`), you can use that component as the type to get typings.

Answer (score 17):

**EDIT: This is no longer the right way to use refs with Typescript. Look at Jeff Bowen's answer and upvote it to increase its visibility.**

Found the answer to the problem. Use refs as below inside the class.

```
refs: {
    [key: string]: (Element);
    stepInput: (HTMLInputElement);
}
```

Thanks @basarat for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: I am still getting `Property 'stepInput' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: Component<any, any> | Element; }'`, when trying to access `this.refs.stepInput`.

Comment: @NikSumeiko, you were getting that error because your `refs` object only had the `[key: string]` entry.

Answer (score 7):

`FIRST ADD AN IMPORT`

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
```

THEN THIS

```
const studentCapacityRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

OR THIS

```
const studentCapacityRef = useRef<HTMLAreaElement>(null);
```

OR THIS

```
const studentCapacityRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

etc...

Answer (score 4):

For those looking on how to do it when you have an array of elements:

```
const textInputRefs = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[]>([])

...

const onClickFocus = (event: React.BaseSyntheticEvent, index: number) => {
    textInputRefs.current[index]?.focus()
};

...

{items.map((item, index) => (
    <textInput
        inputRef={(ref) => textInputs.current[index] = ref}
    />
    <Button
        onClick={event => onClickFocus(event, index)}
    />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use the callback style (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) as recommended on React's documentation you can add a definition for a property on the class:

```
export class Foo extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
// You don't need to use 'references' as the name
references: {
    // If you are using other components be more specific than HTMLInputElement
    myRef: HTMLInputElement;
} = {
    myRef: null
}
...
 myFunction() {
    // Use like this
    this.references.myRef.focus();
}
...
render() {
    return(<input ref={(i: any) => { this.references.myRef = i; }}/>)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For typescript user no constructor required.

...

```
private divRef: HTMLDivElement | null = null

getDivRef = (ref: HTMLDivElement | null): void => {
    this.divRef = ref
}

render() {
    return <div ref={this.getDivRef} />
}
```

...

Answer (score 2):

If you wont to forward your `ref`, in Props interface you need to use `RefObject<CmpType>` type from `import React, { RefObject } from 'react';`

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a complete example, here is my little test script for getting user input when working with React and TypeScript. Based partially on the other comments and this link https://medium.com/@basarat/strongly-typed-refs-for-react-typescript-9a07419f807#.cdrghertm

```
/// <reference path="typings/react/react-global.d.ts" />

// Init our code using jquery on document ready
$(function () {
    ReactDOM.render(<ServerTime />, document.getElementById("reactTest"));
});

interface IServerTimeProps {
}

interface IServerTimeState {
    time: string;
}

interface IServerTimeInputs {
    userFormat?: HTMLInputElement;
}

class ServerTime extends React.Component<IServerTimeProps, IServerTimeState> {
    inputs: IServerTimeInputs = {};

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { time: "unknown" }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Server time: { this.state.time }</div>
                <input type="text" ref={ a => this.inputs.userFormat = a } defaultValue="s" ></input>
                <button onClick={ this._buttonClick.bind(this) }>GetTime</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    // Update state with value from server
    _buttonClick(): void {
    alert(`Format:${this.inputs.userFormat.value}`);

        // This part requires a listening web server to work, but alert shows the user input
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: { format: this.inputs.userFormat.value },
        url: "/Home/ServerTime",
        success: (result) => {
            this.setState({ time : result });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From React type definition

```
    type ReactInstance = Component<any, any> | Element;
....
    refs: {
            [key: string]: ReactInstance
    };
```

So you can access you refs element as follow

```
stepInput = () => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['stepInput']);
```

without redefinition of refs index.

As @manakor mentioned you can get error like

> Property 'stepInput' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]:
>   Component | Element; }

if you redefine refs(depends on IDE and ts version you use)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a different approach - you can simply cast your ref, something like:

```
let myInputElement: Element = this.refs["myInput"] as Element
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do this, in that case
to grab a ref

`let input: HTMLInputElement =   ReactDOM.findDOMNode<HTMLInputElement>(this.refs.input);`

Comment: let input: HTMLInputElement =   ReactDOM.findDOMNode<HTMLInputElement>(this.refs['input']);

Answer (score -1):

```
class SelfFocusingInput extends React.Component<{ value: string, onChange: (value: string) => any }, {}>{
    ctrls: {
        input?: HTMLInputElement;
    } = {};
    render() {
        return (
            <input
                ref={(input) => this.ctrls.input = input}
                value={this.props.value}
                onChange={(e) => { this.props.onChange(this.ctrls.input.value) } }
                />
        );
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.ctrls.input.focus();
    }
}
```

put them in an object

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: This answer is setting ctrls.input to a strongly typed element, which is the strongly-typed way to go.    This is a better "Typescript" choice.