# React Refs with TypeScript: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forward-reference, react-ref

I'm building a React application using TypeScript.

I want to create button, that scrolls to a header of a child component on my main page.

I've created a ref in the child component, following [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796267/how-to-use-refs-in-react-with-typescript) answer and (tried to) use [forward refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components) to access it on my parent component.

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  private testTitleRef!: RefObject<HTMLHeadingElement>;

  scrollToTestTitleRef = () => {
    if (this.testTitleRef.current !== null) {
      window.scrollTo({
        behavior: "smooth",
        top: this.testTitleRef.current.offsetTop
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <Child ref={this.testTitleRef} />
  }
}

interface Props {
  ref: RefObject<HTMLHeadingElement>;
}

export class Child extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <h1 ref={this.props.ref}>Header<h1 />
  }
}
```

Unfortunately when I trigger `scrollToTestTitleRef` I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'current' of undefined
```

Meaning that the ref is undefined. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
[Estus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus) helped me to create the ref. But when I trigger the `scrollToTestTitleRef()` event, it doesn't scroll.
When I `console.log` `this.testTitleRef.current` I get the output:

```
{"props":{},"context":{},"refs":{},"updater":{},"jss":{"id":1,"version":"9.8.7","plugins":{"hooks":{"onCreateRule":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"onProcessRule":[null,null,null],"onProcessStyle":[null,null,null,null,null,null],"onProcessSheet":[],"onChangeValue":[null,null,null],"onUpdate":[null]}},"options":{"plugins":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}},"sheetsManager":{},"unsubscribeId":null,"stylesCreatorSaved":{"options":{"index":-99999999945},"themingEnabled":false},"sheetOptions":{},"theme":{},"_reactInternalInstance":{},"__reactInternalMemoizedUnmaskedChildContext":{"store":{},"storeSubscription":null},"state":null}
```

**Note:** I deleted the keys of `cacheClasses`, `_reactInternalFiber` and 
`__reactInternalMemoizedMaskedChildContext`, because they contained cyclic dependencies.

So current doesn't seem to have a key of `offsetTop`. Does this maybe have something to do with the fact that in my real application the child component is wrapped inside material-ui's `withStyle` and React-Redux' `connect`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` non-null assertion operator suppresses the actual problem. There is no way in JavaScript/TypeScript how `testTitleRef` property could be assigned from being used as `<Child ref={this.titleRef} />`, so it stays undefined (there's also inconsistency with `testTitleRef` and `titleRef`).

It should be something like:

```
  private testTitleRef: React.createRef<HTMLHeadingElement>();

  scrollToTestTitleRef = () => {
      if (!this.testTitleRef.current) return;

      window.scrollTo({
        behavior: "smooth",
        top: this.testTitleRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY
      });
  };
  render() {
    return <Child scrollRef={this.testTitleRef} />
  }
```

and

```
export class Child extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <h1 ref={this.props.scrollRef}>Header<h1 />
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The inconsistency was just because I jotted down that examply quickly for this question. I created the ref your way, and it doesn't crash anymore. It still doesn't work. I added more info to the question. Could you please help me further?

Comment: I didn't pay attention to Child, but yes, a ref is class instance, not DOM element. You could do `el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.testTitleRef.current)` but actually this may not be a good idea to do this with `ref` because this wouldn't work at all with function component (they have no refs), also a component may render to multiple DOM elements or no elements at all. I'd suggest to refactor the code to make components decide themselves which element should expose as scroll box, e.g. `<Child scrollRef={this.testTitleRef} />` and assign `this.props.scrollRef.current` to `h1` ref inside Child.

Comment: Btw, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828976/3731501 , it already suggests something like this, notice that it passes `refProp` and not `ref` to a child.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You are helping me tremendously. I switched `ref` to `refProp` and set the ref to `h1` now it scrolls, but it scrolls to the top of the document, and not to the header of the child. If I log `this.props.scrollRef.current` it correctly gives out the `<h1 />`. Do you have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Can you provide a demo to debug?

Comment: Hardly, because the real application has hundres of lines of code. If I strip something it might be what causes the bug. If I console.log `this.props.scrollRef.current.offsetTop` it gives me 32px what is the height of the heading and it's margin, but not the total distance between the element and the top of the window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183439/discussion-between-j-hesters-and-estus).

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the problem here, and you need absolute Y offset. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Comment: Thank you  Here is the code that I ended up using: `this.testTitleRef.current.parentElement!.getBoundingClientRect().top`. Would you mind adding this to your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure. But `parentElement` looks fishy. Why is it needed here? I wouldn't expect it to work ok in the code you posted, it would refer to Parent's container instead of Child's `<h1>`.

Comment: To be honest that was just try and error until the scroll worked correctly 

Comment: This depends on the layout but I'd expect `parentElement` to be harmful here.