# Type ref is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to use a ref for my elements, but I get an error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
Type '{ ref: RefObject<unknown>; letter: string; draggable: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & content'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & content'.
```

I've searched online for a while, but I can't find anything helpful to my case.

Here's my code:

```
Content.tsx
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Box } from './Box';

function Content() {
    const onSubmitAnswer = () => {
        console.log("da");
    };

    const test = React.createRef();
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Box {...{ letter: 'C', draggable: 1 }} ref={test}/>
            <Box {...{ letter: 'A', draggable: 0 }} />
            <Box {...{ letter: 'B', draggable: 0 }} />
            <Box {...{ letter: 'C', draggable: 0 }} />
            <Box {...{ letter: 'D', draggable: 0 }} />
            <button onClick={onSubmitAnswer}>Trimite!</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Content;
```

and Box.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './Box.css';
import Draggable, { DraggableData, DraggableEvent } from 'react-draggable';

export type content = {
    letter: string,
    draggable: number
}



export function Box(props: content) {
    const el = React.createRef();

    if(props.draggable) {
        return (
            <Draggable>
            <div className="box box-drag">
                <span className="box-content">
                  {props.letter}
                </span>
              </div>
            </Draggable>
            );
    }
    return (
        <div className="box">
            <span className="box-content" ref={el => {console.log(el?.getBoundingClientRect());}}>
              {props.letter}
            </span>
          </div>
        );
}
```

I think I know why this happens - Box is a component, and when I pass ref as an attribute (like I would do with a JSX tag) it doesn't behave the same (it goes in the props).

Is there any way to use ref/className/name on a component just as I'd use them on a JSX element?

//edit:
typescript playground link:

```
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=7#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGbZFIDKMKMScAvnKVBCHAORSoacDcAKFCRYXAHQB6AEIQAHuLSFCA4eGjwAIlBQBzXSgBGAGyTY82vQZNJNdFNkv6jpgKIA3JADt4zVuy4edBgAWgATHWcbVUEYAE8wBjQIH294AF5cQTgcuFMYeigALjhCGChgL11MbNyIqxckEq98EEMkKEFGQUFSfC8MYBS4WTkACjA2MEIS5NSfAEos3LhgUgmpwnF6qNMlnFqVnJ4YfCgvODHDo5WAHidrUwA+a5uc27Dgdzg0YxRlAByKBASHSACJDPI4JC5OFImCXm8kXBboQwCgLr9-oQgSDwTCQnN6D4Ea9kSscJMINNxPlCt1yTdbpI0RjEYz3pJPu52eTmQ9GrzkQshCsGbkTmcLlckR8vj8-oDgaCIfJSRzUejMYqccr8fJCSliTB1RzcFSaXSOuK+SytUKmVyvg7ciKuj0+gMYEMLgBhI1pMb7a5zMpwFJUfCGEDAGAAQS8hAA7h04Jkg2mnss3qGIKZaRBdGMwWEUGC3WKhCGUmH6GHMshgoogvQyLcMXEnkHRblrpLzpcye9uS6maNcOJJ3grcUuL7ONgdo8mnAAIxMZg8UjpHB1mDMSSjo63cc4SfiadIAodEqcOMLuBLxolAAMG7gh6Hx9P58v19nnDSA+T42K+76fhqP5TnkV6FLe86LpEy5gYwB5HncUEXjB-63powFIc+cBvqhH7obktyGPgBTDCkvrGMAaAANY7hGUYxvGiYplAjBPAAKhU7FIAAhMylHUV4R7MiO1xut0ghIHIojwGESCkCg+DGPA-rzDA-BAA
```

Comment: `Ref` usually should have a type (`Ref<T>`). In your case, I suspect it's `createRef<Box>` although I don't remember whether it's the proper typing for a custom component. The simplest to get around with that (although it's not a beautiful solution since you lose intellisense), is to just do `createRef<any>`. You might want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796267/how-to-use-refs-in-react-with-typescript . The problem is basically that `Ref<unknown>` cannot satisfy the `ref` constraints of the child.

Comment: @briosheje it doesn't work with createRef<any>, I get the same message.

Comment: could you please share minimum reproducible example in one file in TypeSsript playground ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I edited the post with the link you requested, but I get a lot of errors that I don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `ref`, you should wrap `Box` into [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html):

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './Box.css';
import Draggable, { DraggableData, DraggableEvent } from 'react-draggable';

type content = {
  letter: string,
  draggable: number
}

const Box = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, content>((props, ref) => {
  if (props.draggable) {
    return (
      <Draggable>
        <div className="box box-drag">
          <span className="box-content">
            {props.letter}
          </span>
        </div>
      </Draggable>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <span className="box-content">
        {props.letter}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
});



function Content() {
  const onSubmitAnswer = () => {
    console.log("da");
  };

  const test = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  return (
    <div>
      <Box {...{ letter: 'C', draggable: 1 }} ref={test} />
      <Box {...{ letter: 'A', draggable: 0 }} />
      <Box {...{ letter: 'B', draggable: 0 }} />
      <Box {...{ letter: 'C', draggable: 0 }} />
      <Box {...{ letter: 'D', draggable: 0 }} />
      <button onClick={onSubmitAnswer}>Trimite!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Content;
```

[PLayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGbZFIDKMKMScAvnKVBCHAORSoacDcAKFCRYXAHQB6AEIQAHuLSFCA4eGjwAIlBQBzXSgBGAGyTY82vQZNJNdFNkv6jpgKIA3JADt4zVuy4edBgAWgATHWcbVUEYAE8wBjQIH294AF5cQTg4Uxh6KAAuOEIYKGAvXUxsuAirFyRir3wQQyQoQUZBQWSvUrhZOThM5GDxUmgAdxQoMLIAHgAJABUAWQAZTWB3V1MQNOxe%20h8APgAKM7A2MEJsHlIASmGTrJzgUjhL68JxOqjTJ44Go5HgwfBQLyfYE5ODzJzWUwnaEw2FhbZwNDGFDKAByKH26QARIZ5HASXJwpFCUiUbTYYQwChIZjsYQ8QTifIQkc0tTkXTcFcIDdxHkCl0BTD5pIGUyaQLpWj3PKUdL4Q0VXAHkIchK4KDwZCztD5kqMVjcfikETyXy6fNZcyLWyrTauTyfHaBTghSKxe09aqZYyvJrFdt5drOlHuoJSPgvBhgCk4ABhFLHGBnQE1Xr9FJUfCGEDAGAAQT6k3aw0%20T3SLyBKLzEFMoogujOhLCKEJUd1QlzKX69H6I14MEUQXoCxWGy2Oz2aXOMZBSDBEKhqqVmpy80GuHEh7w-qKXFTnGwfwRjTgAEYmMx7ukcCOYMxJDvYfucIfxMe1wUxScGWF61JE17FAADA%20cAfvye6kj%20R65AB7RAdIoFXg0UEwXB9rfr%20-75GhZ6YeB2FwNBjDvp%20CFDEhf4ocRp6cJoZH1DYOHUbBtGGPg%20QpikqbGMAaAANbPgWRYluWlYBicyzlDJSAAITSnxAmhiakjbjUUZdIISByKI8BhEgpAoPgxjwOmqQ%20PwQA)

`ref` expects to be HTML element. Thats why I have provided `HTMLDivElement` for `const test = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();`. It is up to you which HTML element it should be.

`Box` is wrapped into `forwardRef` with explicit generic arguments: `React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, content>`