# How do you set the style of an element obtained from a callback ref?

Tags: reactjs

My react library obtains a ref by giving the client a callback ref function to put on the element that the library is to operate on:

Conceptually:

```
// --- library

export registerTarget = () => {
   return (targetRef) => {
      if (targetRef) {
         targetRef.style = {color: "red"};  // or more funky library stuff.
      }
   }
} 

// --- component

const targetMe = library.registerTarget('my-element');

return (
   <div ref={targetMe}>This is my element for the library to operate on</div>
);
```

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726702/554807) that when you make the ref using createRef, then it's type is `React.RefObject<T>`, but when you get the ref using a ref callback, you get the actual element.

The problem is that you are allowed to assign to `ref.current.style` when `ref` is a `React.RefObject<T>`, but you are not allowed to assign to ref.style when ref is the thing that you got from a ref callback.

Or at least, I can't work out how to type the thing that I get from a ref-callback: I've tried `HTMLElement`, but the error is that `ref.style` is read-only in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, you can't mutate `ref.style` since it's read-only however you can change the css properties inline-y:

```js
const registerTarget = () => {
  return (targetRef: HTMLElement | null) => {
    if (targetRef) {
      targetRef.style.color = "red"; // or more funky library stuff.
    }
  };
};
```

[CodeSandbox Demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-zxl3wu?file=/src/App.tsx)