# useRef validation error when using current and referencing it against an input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

The following code works fine but trying to address the error alert coming from `Typescript`.

It keeps warning me with following error for the usage of `ref.currrent.value`.

```
ERROR 1. TS18048: 'ref.current' is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Fair enough. So I add in a check as follows.

```
const result = ref.current && ref.current.value;
```

This now throws following error.

```
ERROR 2. TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

Error also shown when I use the `useRef` for an input as show in code below.

I have tried to force these types on the `useRef<Type>` but results in same error.

> ERROR 3: TS2322: Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type
> 'LegacyRef | undefined'.   Type
> 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type
> 'RefObject'.     Types of property 'current' are
> incompatible.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'HTMLInputElement | null'.

How can I address these errors. No issues faced in the logic but the red squiggly lines defeats the purpose of using Typescript. Pls advice. Thanks.

P.S: This is a nextjs project if that matters.

State management in use here is Zustand but leaving that tag out cos believe it is irrelevant here.

Issue is with `useRef` hook validation I believe.

Code:

```
'use client';

import {useRef} from "react";
import useStore from "../utils/store";

const Input = () => {
  const addPerson = useStore((state) => state.addPerson);
  const ref = useRef();

  const add = () => {
    const result = ref.current && ref.current.value; // ERROR 2
    ref.current.value = ''; // ERROR 1
    addPerson({
      name: result,
      id: '2',
    });
  }

  return (
  <div>
    <input placeholder='write something' type='text' ref={ref} /> {/* ERROR 3*/} 
    <button onClick={add}>Add Person</button>
  </div>
 );
};

export default Input;
```

Image to show the red error lines:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work

```
'use client';

import {useRef} from "react";
import useStore from "../utils/store";

const Input = () => {

  const addPerson = useStore((state) => state.addPerson);
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const add = () => {
    const result = ref.current && ref.current.value; // ERROR 2
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.value = ''; // ERROR 1
    }
    addPerson({
      name: result,
      id: '2',
    });
  }

  return (
  <div>
    <input placeholder='write something' type='text' ref={ref} /> {/* ERROR 3*/} 
    <button onClick={add}>Add Person</button>
  </div>
 );
};

export default Input;
```

Here is the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61680609/2122822), I just put an extra falsy check

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. It addresses error 1 and 2. Error 3 remains.

Comment: Scratch that is fine. Restarting Webstorm removed the error 3. Cheers.