# Angular - how to get file in IE

Tags: angularjs, file, internet-explorer

I cant get files from input file on IE9/8. 10 works.

```
<input type="file" file-model="onFileSelected($files)" />

app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {           
            var fn = $parse(attrs["fileModel"]);
            element.on('change', function(e) {
                console.log(e.target.files);
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

e.target.files is undefined on IE9

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830058/ie8-input-type-file-get-files
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207388/is-it-possible-to-select-and-upload-multiple-files-at-one-time-in-internet-explo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207388/is-it-possible-to-select-and-upload-multiple-files-at-one-time-in-internet-explo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830058/ie8-input-type-file-get-files).

However, may I recommend you take a look at [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload). If you need to upload multiple files at once, it handles the abstraction of the file input for most browsers by using a flash shim.