# uploading file using multiple & php

Tags: php, upload, count

i am trying to upload file using the below method with the following code :

```
    echo "<form method='POST' action='uploadfile.php?action=addok' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type=\"file\" multiple=\"true\" name=\"userfile[]\"  />
            <input type='submit' value=' add '>
            </form>";

    if ($_GET['action'] == 'addok') {

      echo "\$_FILES['userfile']=".count($_FILES['userfile'])."<br />\$_FILES['userfile']['name']=".count($_FILES['userfile']['name'])."<br />\$_FILES=".count($_FILES)."<br />";
    }
```

it only returns 0 for all count.
if i upload only 1 , it returns the count , otherwise .. nothing ..
i'm trying to solve its issue since yesterday .
can anyone please help out ?

Comment: do a `var_dump($_FILES)` instead to see what's really in there. PHP has some truly moronic ideas of how to build $_FILES when you're doing multiple same-name uploads.

Comment: I'm guessing that your `returns 0` is because you're trying to upload more than one file in a single pass. If that's the case, then you'll need a `foreach` – *"it only returns 0 for **all** count. if i upload only 1"*

Comment: i mean below :) , i wrote the first line in morning where i wrote the code back then before my question and forgot to double check it.

Comment: @fred-ii- i just tried with no luck , same issue..

Comment: @MarcB `var_dump($_FILES)` result is `array(0) { }`
still same issue..

Comment: then no upload is being performed at all. not even a failing one.

Comment: if i try with one file , it works fine .. :
`array(1) { ["userfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "art.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpvzNbRD" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(43983) } } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution ::

it apears that the issue is not in the code as it is in browser .

it was not working in firefox, opera or chrome because of addon or other issue i think .

i did run firefox in safemode `click shift + firefox icon to open in safe mode` and it worked.

this is incase anyone faced same issue again .

Note :
if someone have an idea how to detect this issue and warn user please be my gust :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($_GET['action'] == 'addok') {

        foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $key=>$val){

              print_r($val);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try this `var_dump($_FILES['userfile']);`

Comment: on multi upload , it returns `NULL`

Comment: did you selected the files and click the add button?

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini, the function max_file_uploads() should have a value higher than 1

Then try this,

```
    <form method="post" action="uploadfile.php?action=addok" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD">
    </form>

    $folder = “/home/username/www/uploading/”;
if (is_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))  {   
    if (move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $folder.$HTTP_POST_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
         Echo “File uploaded”;
    } else {
         Echo “File not moved to destination folder. Check permissions”;
    };
} else {
     Echo “File is not uploaded.”;
};
```

You will need to make sure your upload folder has the correct permissions. chmod -R 777 to change permission so that php can upload to that folder.

Things to note though are that IE < 10.0 does not support multiple file uploads via the "multiple" attribute as the File API is still a working draft, http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

[HTML5 input type file's multiple attribute not working in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987936/html5-input-type-files-multiple-attribute-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: did you check your permissions?

Comment: yes , i tried on my localhost as well . nothing .. and as i mentioned in other posts , it works with single file only.!

Comment: remove multiple from the input and try that. then add 2 more copies of the input field and see if it works with that.

Comment: have you checked your php.ini, the function max_file_uploads() should have a value higher than 1.

Comment: it is set to 20 .and code works with single upload but doesnt work with multiple..

Comment: try using 2 input fields instead of multiple, I suspect the issue may be with the multiple attribute. Also try a different browser as older versions of IE do not work with this attribute.

Comment: i did 15 min ago , it WORKS with ie only .. not firefox or opera ,i need the multiple not the regular method .i am searching for a solution as well for that and if i find i will post it here .. and if you have please assist :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing count of $ _FILES, which will always be 1:

try:

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='uploadfile.php?action=addok' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type=\"file\" multiple=\"true\" name=\"userfile[]\"  />
                <input type='submit' value=' add '>
                </form>";

        if ($_GET['action'] == 'addok') {
          echo "<pre>";
            print_r($_FILES);
            echo "</pre>";
          echo "\$_FILES['userfile']=".count($_FILES['userfile'])."<br />\$_FILES['userfile']['name']=".count($_FILES['userfile']['name'])."<br />\$_FILES=".count($_FILES['userfile']['name'])."<br />";
        }
```

print_r:

```
Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => file1.txt
                    [1] => file2.txt
                    [2] => file3.txt
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text/plain
                    [1] => text/plain
                    [2] => text/plain
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php1F5C.tmp
                    [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php1F5D.tmp
                    [2] => C:\wamp\tmp\php1F5E.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

result:

```
$_FILES['userfile']=5
$_FILES['userfile']['name']=3
$_FILES=3
```

Comment: didnt work as well ..
returns :
`Array
(
)
$_FILES['userfile']=0
$_FILES['userfile']['name']=0
$_FILES=0`
try it yourself : http://hussein.be/tst.php
   also on localhost not working..

Comment: if i choose 1 file it works fine , if i choose more than 1 file , $_FILES is empty ..