# IE9 +Older HTML Multiupload Input Fallback

Tags: html, file-upload, html-input

I have a web application and most of the users use IE 11 there is no problem with multiply file upload. My problem is that some users use IE 9 and older ([HTML5 input type file's multiple attribute not working in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987936/html5-input-type-files-multiple-attribute-not-working-in-ie)) there I cant use it.

I need something like "Conditional comments" for it, but with it, it wont work because IE11 ignores it.

In need something in my html like this:

```
if(Multiupload supports){
 <multiply input tag> 
}else{
 <single input tag>
}
```

Is there a way to choose the upload method browser specific?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using something that will allow you to write conditional logic in HTML (such as PHP, AngularJS, Handlebars, ect...) then you will not be able to write a conditional statement based off of a `Multiupload` variable like the example you provided.

**The Pure HTML Way**

Since we know that the multiple upload will not work in Internet Explorer 9 or 8, you can use IE [Conditional Comments](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/) to switch between single or multiple upload, depending on the browser version.

```
<!--[if (!IE 8)|(!IE 9)]><!-->
  <p>Not IE8, or IE9. Multiple Upload</p>
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if (IE 8)|(IE 9)]>
  <p>IE8, or IE9. Single Upload</p>
<![endif]-->
```

This will show the single upload for IE 9 and lower, and the multiple upload for everything else.

Comment: argh, i make a mistake in my tries :D .... thank you :) ... bounty comes in one hour